# Stop executing setInterval function on loading of a new tab in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, setinterval

I have given a setInterval function inside a useEffect as it has to dispatch an action for every 28 min, and this setInterval will start only when the user is logged in (isLogged variable provides us whether the user is logged in or not), it is working as expected, but if I open a new tab, it starts a new 28 min interval in that new tab which I don't expect.

**My Requirement -**

- Every 28 min there should be a dispatch event.
- If the user logs in to one tab and works for 20 min and opens a new
  tab, in the next 8 min dispatch event should occur in both the tabs
  at the same time.

**Code**

```
const isLogged = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer.loggedIn); // provide boolean value
const intervalId = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
   // To check in between if user is logged out and to stop setInterval
   if(isLogged === false){
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
      return;
}
    dispatch(refreshUserToken());
}, 1000 * 60 * 28);

    return () => {
   clearInterval(intervalId.current)
}
},[isLogged])
```

I don't have any idea on how to do this concept, could someone please help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: If by a "new tab" you mean a browser tab, like a new page, you should keep track of this somewhere else: `localStorage`, server, etc..

Comment: @cSharp, yea I do mean about the new browser tab

Comment: Redux state is expected to reset when refreshing a page or opening in new tab/window.
You're using useSelector which will update if new tab opened. Hence the issue.
To solve this you might need to use redux-state-sync and redux-persist.
Checkout these packages. It might help.
Thanks.

Comment: @RanveerSequeira, So what should I do to not happen like that?

Comment: If the activity is depending on the log status, you save time handling the logic serverside, at each new visit you check on server how much time is left for the refresh token to be sent, and you send the expire time back, so the interval is always updated.